# How can I stop Keras from printing after calling model.predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am training a keras sequential model and now wish to predict a value. I run the following single line

```py
agent.model.predict(np.array([0,0,0,0]).reshape(1,4))
```

and get the following output displayed in my notebook

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 29ms/step
array([[0.00760011, 0.01811639]], dtype=float32)
```

How do I stop Keras from showing the first line in the output?

Comment: set verbose=0 in model.predict

Answer (score 27):

As mentioned by **Gerry P**, to prevent Keras from printing the output of model.predict(), set the verbose argument to 0 as follows:

```
agent.model.predict(np.array([0,0,0,0]).reshape(1,4),verbose = 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Better to write:

```
agent.model.predict(np.array([0,0,0,0]).reshape(1,4),verbose=None)
```

Then it does not show the progress any More!

Answer (score 0):

The default value of verbose is 0, so the above answer is wrong. I have this problem when fitting my model that is using MTCNN.

> ```
> model = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge')
> ```

```
  model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 48ms/step

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/), the `verbose` argument of the  `predict` function defaults to `"auto"` which [will be](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.12.0/keras/engine/training.py#L3941) 1 for most cases, or 2 when used with `ParameterServerStrategy`. So the above answer is actually correct.

Your example makes use of the `fit` function, which, according to the above documentation and the source code [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.12.0/keras/engine/training.py#L1339), has the same defaults (i.e. `"auto"`).